# Is this a standard practice to use queues FIFO this way?

Tags: c, linux, communication, interrupt

Let's say I have to work on a resource-stingy platform, the processor my program will be running on is rather low end (MCU, 80486, whatnot) and I try to implement this object oriented, event-driven programming model.

The source of the events comes from, of course, interrupts. Since the processor is rather slow, and I don't want to drop any interrupt event (which is BTW, quite often the case for MCUs, if I can't respond in time, I mask the relevant interrupt source and stops taking in interrupts altogether) what I'm going to do is I'm gonna have an interrupt event struct detailing everything, then I'm going to build a FIFO array, which contains not these events, but references (pointer) to these events, and if I care, I can make this FIFO a 2way linked list, as long as I watch out for the size or a memory leak may happen.

So every time an interrupt arrives, I "cram" all its information with a setter of some sort into the aforementioned event struct and push it into the FIFO, and I pop and deal with it later.

I believe this is particularly useful when the interrupts are mainly communication related, for example, if I were to implement a low power, standalone MQTT server.

My question is, is this something completely amateur, something only a "bad" programmer will do, or is it rather by-the-book?

Comment: yes, it is common practice. Eg see description of interrupt handlers on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler

Comment: You have to be sure that over time, your code can process interrupts faster than they arrive so that you don't run out of resources.  If that's not feasible, you will have to decide which interrupts to discard.

Comment: @harmic  If I may, what book has detailed description on these programming models? I'm sure there are books which focus more on programming principles instead of tips and tricks.